# msbuild and file version change

Tags: .net, git, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am trying to make the following build scenario in my environment (using Jenkins and git) on my .net projects which are all under abc solution:

1. Pull the changes from git.
2. Build the solution that only the projects that were updated turing the pull will be built and also the dependencies.
3. The build command should build these projects and its dependencies with a specific assembly version. for example: 1.2.3.4
4. Each assemblyinfo.cs of the projects that were build should be changed to

> ```
> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
> [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
> ```

Any idea on a nice way for doing step 3 and 4 ?
I tried to run this command line but it did not gave me the result I wanted.

```
msbuild.exe abc.sln /p:Configuration=Release;VersionAssembly=1.2.3.4
```

Appreciate your kindly answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MSBuild.Community.Tasks`](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) and add the following to the `*.csproj` project files:

```
<Import Project=".\tasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"  
    OutputFile="AssemblyInfo.cs" 
    AssemblyVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)" 
    AssemblyFileVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)" />
```

Run `msbuild` and pass the desired build number as a parameter:

```
msbuild abc.sln /p:BUILD_NUMBER=1.2.3.4
```